# "Permission denied" reading from a process-substitution FIFO in an unprivileged child process

Tags: linux, bash, unix, permissions

Consider the following, observed with bash 4.4 on a Linux 3.19 kernel:

```
# in reality, this may access files "nobody" isn't allowed
get_a_secret() { printf '%s\n' "This is a secret"; }

# attach a process substitution reading the secret to FD 10
exec 10< <(get_a_secret)

# run a less-privileged program that needs the secret, passing it the file descriptor.
chpst -u nobody:nobody -- cat /dev/fd/10
```

...or the shorter/simpler:

```
chpst -u nobody:nobody -- cat <(get_a_secret)
```

Either fails in a manner akin to the following:

```
cat: /proc/self/fd/10: Permission denied
```

---

So, two branches to this question:

- What's going on here?
- Is there a way to get the desired behavior (passing the ability to read the secret through to the single child process being invoked in a way that doesn't persistently expose that secret to other processes running as "nobody") without exposing the FIFO's output to other processes?

<sub>(Yes, I'm well aware that I need to lock down ptrace and `/proc/*/mem` to prevent another process running as "nobody" from pulling the secret out of the client as it's being read; that said, that's (1) something I can do, and (2) when the process is only run before any potentially-attacker-controlled executables are invoked, less exposure than allowing any process running as `nobody` to pull the secret out of `/proc/*/environ` for the full duration of that process).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The following workaround avoids this issue:

```
exec 10< <(get_a_secret)
chpst -u nobody:nobody -- sh -c 'cat <&10'
```

Note the redirection being written as `<&10` -- **not** `</dev/fd/10` or `</proc/self/fd/10` (on platforms which provide `/dev/fd` -- on platforms without this facility, bash rewrites it into a `fdup2()` call).

---

An answer with an explanation of the behavior (and perhaps a workaround that allows programs that *don't* accept a FD number as input to act on the read side?) would be in a position to supercede this one. :)